# No matching function call call to constructor in header file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have seen similar questions asked and tried their solutions but the answers to them do not seem to work. I have the following code:

**.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using std::string; using std::vector;

struct DialogueNode;

struct DialogueOption   {
    string text;
    DialogueNode *next_node;
    int return_code;

    DialogueOption(string t, int rc, DialogueNode * nn) : text{t}, 
        return_code{rc}, next_node{nn}   {}
};

struct DialogueNode {
    string text;
    vector <DialogueOption> dialogue_options;
    DialogueNode();
    DialogueNode(const string &);
};

struct DialogueTree {
    DialogueTree()  {}
    void init();
    void destroyTree();

    int performDialogue();
private:
    vector <DialogueNode*> dialogue_nodes;
};
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "dialogue_tree.h"

DialogueNode::DialogueNode(const string &t) : text{t} {}

void DialogueTree::init()   {
    string s = "Hello";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {
        DialogueNode *node = new DialogueNode(s);
        dialogue_nodes.push_back(node);
        delete node;
    }
}

void DialogueTree::destroyTree()    {

}

int DialogueTree::performDialogue() {
    return 0;
}

int main()  {
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error: `error: no matching function for call to ‘DialogueNode:: DialogueNode(std::__cxx11::string&)’ DialogueNode *node = new DialogueNode(s);`

**EDIT** additional notes on error

```
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note: candidate: DialogueNode::DialogueNode()
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note: candidate: DialogueNode::DialogueNode(const DialogueNode&)
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const DialogueNode&’
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note: candidate: DialogueNode::DialogueNode(DialogueNode&&)
dialogue_tree.h:17:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘DialogueNode&&’
```

Which makes no sense to me because I have the constructor defined to take a `string` as an argument.

Comment: Might be unrelated but what's `dialogue_nodes` ? Looks like you have not shown the _relevant_ code

Comment: @P0W it's a vector of `DialogueNode` pointers in the `DialogueTree` class I will attach that snipper code as well

Comment: Doing the best I can with incomplete code, [can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QnxPYc3STZWa9XSx).

Comment: @chris I'll post the full code just thought it'd be more readable this way

Comment: @chris full code is up. I'm compiling as C++11 as well

Comment: It is often more readable to have less code, but it's also harder to deal with incomplete code. Combine the advantages of less code and complete code by making a [mcve].

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you calling  `delete node`?  That's making the pointer you just shoved into the vector a rather bad pointer.

Comment: Deleting the pointer will affect the copy that I just pushed into my vector? @donkopotamus

Comment: @quantik You're not "deleting the pointer" ... you're deleting the object that the pointer pointed to.  So yes, your "copy of the pointer" in the vector, that points to that very same object, the one that just got deleted, is now severely compromised.

Answer (score 2):

You've declared your constructor as:

```
DialogueNode(const string);
```

But defined it as:

```
DialogueNode(const string &t);
```

Those two aren't the same; the former takes a `const string` while the latter takes a `const string` reference. You'll have to add the `&` to specify a reference argument:

```
DialogueNode(const string &);
```

Comment: Yeah originally I wasn't as reference and it was giving me the same issue. I decided to make that change and didn't update the program fully. This did not fix the problem - unfortunately..

Comment: This would cause an error like "not declared in class" or maybe "unresolved external", not the error in the post about argument passing.

Answer (score 0):

it is because in the constructor you are specifying that the parameter will be a string of constant type and when creating an object you are passing a string. The type mismatch is the problem, either fix the constructor parameter to string or change when you are creating an object.

Comment: I updated the problem this does not fix the issue unfortunately

Comment: Non-const arguments can match const parameters (whether the parameter is a reference or not). This is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding in my knowledge!